# Dual Sim but one outgoing number

Tags: dual-sim

I have a dual sim phone and am starting to do a bit of extra free lancing work on top of my regular job.

I have my own personal SIM which I have a contract that gives me unlimited calls. What I would like to do is get another SIM as a work number to give to clients. To keep this SIM active I just want to pay the minimum amount (I think it is 10 Euro every 6 months or something like that) so that clients phone my work SIM and not have my personal number.

With having unlimited calls on my personal SIM I'd like to phone my clients back using my personal SIM as it costs me nothing extra but make it look like I'm phoning from my work SIM.

Is it possible to do this? Is there an app that can control this?

I could always just phone my clients using my personal SIM and withhold my number so my number doesn't show but that's not really what I'm after.

Does anyone know is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: No, that is not possible, partially.
What you are searching is something like caller ID spoofing, which I don't recommend using, or even researching.

Comment: If you have "free calls" from your landline as well, can add numbers to that, and have a phone box supporting it (these conditions would match in my case), you could configure a call-through at the phone box and use a call-prefixer app on your Android phone to route your calls that way. They then would turn up for the called person as initiated by that "additional number" assigned to your landline and configured there for call-through.

Answer (score 1):

For this I recommend using Skype Out. you can authorize skype to give your actual cell number as caller id when making a Skype Out call. I do this when travelling overseas, my outgoing calls say they are my US number. I let incoming calls just go to voice mail of my real cell phone number so I don't have to pay international fees, and immediately call people back using skype out. My clients never have to know I'm out of the country.

Answer (score -2):

Using a redirection service, you can do this,

Remember that changing a number may be ILLEGAL depending on the area you live in.
In most scenarios it's only calling someone from an unauthorized number,
 So it's good to find someone that actually owns the number they are trying to identify as...

If you are Actually the authorised and registered owner of the work phone,
 I gather that you have permission to identify yourself as this number, And anyone researching the number will still lead back to you, it should be fine ( i say fine as in Not Identity Theft )

If you enable unknown souces you can install the app in the link THINGS TO KNOW FIRST !

1 • ONLY USE IF YOU HAVE AUTHORIZATION TO SPOOF/USE/MASK THE WORK NUMBER FROM THE OWNER OF THE MOBILE NUMBER !

2• DO NOT TRY TO SPOOF/USE/MASK THE NUMBER YOU ARE CALLING FROM ! THIS COULD CAUSE A NETWORK LOOP AND MAY CAUSE UNWANTED TECHNICAL CHARGES ON YOUR PHONE PLAN/CREDIT OR AT THE NETWORK PROVIDERS EXPENSE !

3• DO NOT USE THIS IN ANY WAY THAT CAN BE FOUND OFFENSIVE AND OR DESTRUCTIVE TOWARDS ANY PERSON, BUSINESS OR INDUSTRY, (" BY DESTRUCTIVE I AM HYPOTHETICALLY SAYING THAT YOU MIGHT HAVE BEEN FIRED AND YOU ARE TRYING TO WRECK YOUR OLD WORK PLACES/'S CHANCE/'S OF SUCCES/'S")

4• YOU UNDERSTAND THAT THIS APP IS FREE TO USE ANYTIME, BUT IT DOES COST A NORMAL OVERSEAS CALL FEE, THIS IS BECAUSE YOUR CALL WILL BE SENT TO A CALL CENTER IN ANOTHER COUNTRY AND REDIRECTED WITH A NEW CALLER ID AND/OR OPTIONAL FUNNY VOICE, THIS COSTS A USUAL OVERSEAS PHONE CALL AMOUNT.. CHECK YOUR PLAN DETAILS FIRST

5•IT CHARGES INTERNATIONAL FEESON MY PHONE IT'S A INTERNATIONAL CALL FEE

> [STILL WANT TO PROCEED ? ... CLICK ON ME FOR APK FILE](http://www.crazycall.net/CrazyCall.apk)